# Null error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null

I am getting the following error;

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object          (evaluating)'document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked').value')question1scoring.js:2
```

The line specified contains the code;

```
var answer = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked').value;
```

I am assuming that it is giving me this error as it not able to create the value when the function is run. Can someone please tell me how to avoid this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the query select didn't find anything, so it returned null, which you tried to take the `.value` of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a ternary operator might work better and avoid the exception:

```
var answer1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked')?true:false;
```

Explanation:

If document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]') is NOT checked, the first part of the ternary operator (the condition) will not be satisfied, so the returned value is "false"; otherwise, it will return "true", as you expect.

Comment: The line of code is retrieving one of two possible values, will the true or false value not overwrite the .value property in that case?

Comment: There are multiple ways to perform this task, and my approach is without using the .value property, since it might happen that it does not exist and triggers an error. In my understanding, you just want to know the answer selected, right?

Comment: There is only an issue if an option isn't picked. I need the value if there is an option picked, I want to feedback to the user if nothing is selected, but only once the function runs.

Comment: I went with if(document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked')) to check to see if it was answered and displayed an error at that stage if it wasn't this has given me the functionality that I was initially looking for. Thanks.